# Actions seem to be blocked on first slide item

Tags: slick.js

I'm using ngx-slide-carousel which I believe wraps the slick-carousel. My config is as follows:

```
{
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    centerMode: true,
    nextArrow: ..
    prevArrow: ...
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
             }
         }
    ]
}
```

Inside a slide, I have a button that does something. Wnen the slides appear, the 2 slides appear in the center because of my config. When I click on the button on the 1st slide, it's not responding. But when i swipe it to the right so that the 1st slide becomes the 2nd slide, the button now responds. Then when i swipe it to the left so it becomes again the 1st slide, the button again does not respond.

Also I noticed when I select the 1st slide itself, it's showing an outline, but the outline is by default disabled. It's surprising that whenever I swipe, whatever lands in the 1st slide, when i click on the slide itself, the outline appears. It doesn't appear in any other positions.

But my major issue is the button that does not respond it if's the 1st slide and whenever it's in the first position.

Comment: Hiya - are you able to replicate this in a fiddle by any chance?